# What do I do about "I/O error: /opt/afp/tools/lib/classes/afp_tools.jar" in an AFP submission?

Tags: isabelle

I am submitting to the AFP (Archive of Formal Proofs) for the first time, and I am getting a build error.  The Isabelle log is:

```
Extract archive
Checking for hidden files
Found no hidden files or directories
Running session checks...
### Building AFP/Tools (/opt/afp/tools/lib/classes/afp_tools.jar) ...
*** I/O error: /opt/afp/tools/lib/classes/afp_tools.jar
```

The bottom line is that I don't know what this is trying to tell me or how to fix it.  At first blush, this seems to have nothing to do with the files I actually submitted, but what do I know?

Hmm.  StackOverflow is asking me to describe what I tried, what I expected to happen, and what actually happened.  Well, I tried submitting my entry to the AFP.  I expected the system to build my entry, because it builds just fine for me and others who've used it, and for the system to tell me that it is by for the most amazing, most beautiful AFP entry that has ever been.  What actually resulted was the above build error that I have no idea what it is trying to tell me.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I got no answer here so I emailed the AFP submit email address.  It seemed that it was a server problem on their end.  So if you get this error message, just email them right away.